# Testing multithreading service methods in mocks

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

For example I want to test the fact that my multi-threaded method is calling the repository methods *n* times if I give him *n* chunks of data from different threads. Of course mocks are not thread safe and even are not supposed to be.

```
[Test]
public void CanSaveCustomersInParallel()
{
    var customers = new List<List<Customer>>
                        {
                            new List<Customer>
                                {
                                    new Customer {FirstName = "FirstName1"},
                                    new Customer {FirstName = "FirstName2"}
                                },
                            new List<Customer>
                                {
                                    new Customer {FirstName = "FirstName3"},
                                    new Customer {FirstName = "FirstName4"}
                                }
                        };
    _serviceCustomers.ParallelSaveBatch(customers);
    _repoCustomers
        .Verify(x => x.SaveBatch(It.IsAny<List<Customer>>()), Times.Exactly(2));
}
```

Of course, this test fails sometimes and sometimes it does not. But it is incorrect in its essence. Can you advise me how to re-write it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the next stub did the trick:

```
internal class ServiceStub: Service<DummyEntity>
{
    private int _count;

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _count; }
    }

    public override void SaveBatch(IEnumerable<object> entities)
    {
       lock(this)
       {
           _count++;
       }
    }

    public ServiceStub(IRepository<DummyEntity> repository):base(repository)
    {
        _count = 0;
    }
}
```

And the unit test looks the next way:

```
    [Test]
    public void CanSaveCustomersInParallel()
    {
        var service = new ServiceStub(new DummyRepository());
        var customers = new List<List<Customer>>
                            {
                                new List<Customer>
                                    {
                                        new Customer {FirstName = "FirstName1"},
                                        new Customer {FirstName = "FirstName2"}
                                    },
                                new List<Customer>
                                    {
                                        new Customer {FirstName = "FirstName3"},
                                        new Customer {FirstName = "FirstName4"}
                                    }
                            };
        service.ParallelSaveBatch(customers);
        Assert.AreEqual(service.Count, customers.Count);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

<del>You might be interested to know that as of [v 4.1, Moq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/moq) now does have much improved thread safety, and you should find tests such as yours, when run in parallel, should now verify as expected.</del>

More on the erratic Moq behaviour [here](https://code.google.com/p/moq/issues/detail?id=249)

Typical issues encountered in versions <= 4.0 included random `NullReferenceException` or `IndexOutOfRangeException`, and `mock.Verify(<>, Times.Exactly(N))` failing (usually with an undercount). As of 4.1, these issues now appear to be <del>fixed</del> [MacGyvered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacGyver#MacGyverisms), ~thanks to the community!

**Edit** As per @Danny's comment below, note that the changes made in 4.1 included [locking the Mock](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/blob/master/Source/Interceptor.cs#L155), which isn't much use if you need to test the parallelism of your code.

Comment: We've just found this not to be true... 4.1 adds `lock (Mock)` around stuff that makes mocks completely useless for multi-threaded code. This doesn't seem "improved"... We've had to roll back to 4.0 because it breaks our multithreading/concurrency tests! :(

Comment: Ouch - I hadn't noted this. [Here is one such example.](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/blob/master/Source/Interceptor.cs#L155)

Comment: My name is Danny, not David ;-)

Comment: I've raised an issue in the hope they care about this breaking change: https://github.com/Moq/moq4/issues/62

Answer (score -1):

A design change can simplify this test.  Create a SaveWorker that does the actual work, and a proxy that does the work of a SaveWork on another thread (same abstraction).  Then a SaveWorkerFactory that returns a ThreadedSaveWorker, given a customer.  Finally, inject a Mock of SaveWorkerFactory into _serviceCustomers, and verify that it does the 2 calls.